# Hive query to get rows where any of the columns is null

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a table in hive which has around 100 columns. How do I write a query which would look something like this -

```
select * 
from table 
where if <any column is null then select> 
      else <do nothing>;
```

I am new to hive and databases so I am not sure how this is possible. I think I can do it using a UDF but I want to do it using only a query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE 1 = CASE 
          WHEN column1 is null OR column2 is null OR....... OR columnN is null THEN 1
          ELSE 0
          END
```

Comment: But how do I check it for all columns? And are you sure that 'is null' is allowed in hive?

Comment: I have more than 100 columns. I cannot do that column1 OR column2 for more than 100 columns?